# SqlFormatter is not available in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am new in Symfony2. I just downloaded Symfony 2.1.3 standard and I am creating my test project (blog). I would like to see which sql queries was send into the database. In the toolbar I can see count of requests which was executed, but when I click on the toolbar button to see details about sql queries I obtain exception Fatal error: Class 'SqlFormatter' not found in vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Doctrine/Bundle/DoctrineBundle/Twig/DoctrineExtension.php.

Is this class located in the doctrine distribution or should I add it into the composer.json and download it separately?

Myth Rush

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just update dependencies via composer.

Comment: this is the first time i wanted to ask a question on SO, but someone asked it "just before me" (8 hours ago), and im glad to find an answer already there! :)